# format imaplib output to a table view instead of list

Tags: python, imaplib

I'm trying to retrieve my emails from our imap server and found that using imaplib is the way to do that. So I found this link https://gist.github.com/robulouski/7441883 that shows the basics on how to use imaplib. I followed the code and changed some of the values respectively so I can login on my email account.

Im still trying to learn but so far this is the modified code that I have:

```
import sys
import imaplib
import getpass
import email
import datetime

email_address = 'test@companyemail.net'
password = 1234

M = imaplib.IMAP4('mail.companyemail.net')

try:
    M.login(email_address, password)
    print "LOGIN SUCCESS!"
except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
    print "LOGIN FAILED!!"
    # ... exit or deal with failure...


def process_mailbox(M):
  rv, data = M.search(None, "ALL")
  if rv != 'OK':
      print "No messages found!"
      return

  for num in data[0].split():
      rv, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
      if rv != 'OK':
          print "ERROR getting message", num
          return

      msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
      print 'Message %s: %s' % (num, msg['Subject'])
      #print 'Raw Date:', msg['Date']
      date_tuple = email.utils.parsedate_tz(msg['Date'])
      if date_tuple:
          local_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
              email.utils.mktime_tz(date_tuple))
          print "Local Date:", \
              local_date.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")

rv, data = M.select("INBOX")
if rv == 'OK':
    print "Processing mailbox...\n"
    process_mailbox(M)
```

The output of the the code above is:

```
OK ['Logged in']
Processing mailbox...

Message 1: test
Raw Date: Fri, 05 Aug 2016 05:38:17 +0800
Local Date: Thu, 04 Aug 2016 14:38:17
Message 2: test email 2
Raw Date: Thu, 4 Aug 2016 14:48:35 -0700
Local Date: Thu, 04 Aug 2016 14:48:35
Message 3: test email 3
Raw Date: Fri, 05 Aug 2016 05:52:33 +0800
Local Date: Thu, 04 Aug 2016 14:52:33
Message 4: Fwd: test email 2
Raw Date: Fri, 05 Aug 2016 05:54:54 +0800
Local Date: Thu, 04 Aug 2016 14:54:54
Message 5: test
Raw Date: Wed, 10 Aug 2016 05:28:02 +0800
Local Date: Tue, 09 Aug 2016 14:28:02
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to output it in a table format so it would look like:

```
|   Message     |               Raw Date            |       Local Date          |
| test          | Fri, 05 Aug 2016 05:38:17 +0800   | Thu, 04 Aug 2016 14:38:17 |   
| test email 2  | Thu, 4 Aug 2016 14:48:35 -0700    | Thu, 04 Aug 2016 14:48:35 |
```

and so on...

Thank you for your help.  :)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954).

Comment: @MatthiasWiehl thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Printing Lists as Tabular Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/python-printing-lists-as-tabular-data)